# Bidirected search on permutations in Java

Tags: java, discrete-mathematics

The concept of a permutation has numerous applications in computer science, for example, in the analysis of sorting algorithms and in implementations of distributed systems. Formally, a permutation is a bijection from a set onto itself. For simplicity, let us restrict ourselves to the sets [n] := {1, 2, . . . , n} of the first n positive integers, and denote by Sn the set of all permutations on [n]. It is often convenient to represent a permutation σ by the
n-tuple (σ(1), σ(2), . . . , σ(n)). Swapping two elements of a permutation yields another permutation. For i, j ∈ [n] let Tij : Sn → Sn be the mapping that swaps the images of i and j, that is, if σ ∈ Sn, then τ := Tij (σ) is given by τ (i) = σ(j), τ (j) = σ(i), and τ (k) = σ(k) if i 6= k 6= j.
Example. Let σ = (2, 4, 3, 1). Then T13(σ) = (3, 4, 2, 1).
Now, consider allowing only swaps with some pairs (i, j). For any integer d ≥ 0, let

Pd := {(i, j) ∈ [n] × [n] : i = j or d ≤ j − i ≤ n − d}

Say that a permutation τ is (d, `)-reachable from σ if there are (i1, j1),(i2, j2), . . . ,(i`, j`) ∈ Pd such that the corresponding swaps transform σ to τ , that is, τ = Ti`j` ◦ · · · ◦ Ti2j2 ◦ Ti1j1(σ).

PROBLEM :

1. Prove that for any positive integer n, the permutation (n, n − 1, . . . , 1) is (1, bn/2c) - reachable from (1, 2, . . . , n).
2. To find out whether τ is (d, `)-reachable from σ, one may apply bidirected search as follows: First generate all permutations that are (d, b`/2c)-reachable from σ. Next generate all permutations that are (d, d`/2e)-reachable from τ . Finally, report “YES” if the two generated sets intersect, and otherwise report “NO”. Describe the algorithm using pseudocode; in particular, describe how the sets of permutations are generated. (You may assume the given arguments are valid: you need not implement error handling.)
3. Implement the algorithm of the previous task using Java Programming Language. Show your code. Use your implementation to solve, for all d = 1, 2, . . . , 4 and `= 1, 2, . . . , 9, whether (9, 8, . . . , 1) is (d,`) - reachable from (1, 2, . . . , 9). Show the results as a 4 × 9 matrix.

Comment: You seem to have copy-pasted a homework assignment rather than asked a question. Please read [ask].

Comment: I can confirm this is the assignment from University of Helsinki's CS Master Program selection. Several of my friends applied and got the same question set.

Answer (score 4):

This is literally the prework for University of Helsinki's CS Master program selection. Please do not answer to this in its current form.

Comment: I can confirm this is the assignment from University of Helsinki's CS Master Program selection in 2019. Several of my friends applied and got the same question set. I'm upvoting your answer for awareness